# React hooks state not updating when mapping

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, state

I am trying to update a row of buttons when the user clicks on them. I have my buttons stored in state that I map over. When I console.log I can see the grid state changing, but it does not rerender my buttons. Where am I going wrong?

```
const Step = ({ active, changeGridByVal, val }) => {
  return <>
    <button onClick={() => changeGridByVal(val)}>{active ? 'X' : 'O'}</button>
  </>
}

const TryPage = () => {

  const [grid, setGrid] = useState([
    ['', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '']
  ])

  function changeGridByVal(val){
    const note = val[0]
    const step = val.substring(2)
    const copy = grid
    copy[note][step] = 'X'
    setGrid(copy)
    console.log(grid)
  }
  
  return <> 
    {grid[0].map((e, i) => {
      return <Step key={i} val={`0-${i}`} changeGridByVal={changeGridByVal} active={e === '' ? false : true}></StepNote>
    })}
    </>
}
```

Answer (score 3):

```
  function changeGridByVal(val){
    const note = val[0]
    const step = val.substring(2)
    const copy = grid
    copy[note][step] = 'X'
    setGrid(copy)
    console.log(grid)
  }
```

`copy` is not actually a copy, it's the original array, just under a different name. When you set state, react does a === between the old and new states and sees that they are the same array, so it does not rerender.

Instead, you need to create a new array, which means making a copy at every level that you change:

```
function changeGridByVal(val){
    const note = val[0]
    const step = val.substring(2)
    const copy = [...grid];
    copy[note] = [...grid[note]];
    copy[note][step] = 'X';
    setGrid(copy)
  }
```

Comment: Alternatively, lodash.cloneDeep can be used to make a clone of any obj: https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#cloneDeep

Answer (score 1):

You are mutating the state directly despite your creating a "copy" of the state array. But frankly, if I undestand your small app correctly, there is an easier way to put it together.

It seem you're just trying to toggle your buttons between O and X. I would you just do this instead:

```
import { useState } from "react";

const Step = ({ active, changeGridByVal, index }) => (
  <button onClick={() => changeGridByVal(index)}>{active ? "X" : "O"}</button>
);

const TryPage = () => {
  const [grid, setGrid] = useState([["O", "O", "O", "O", "O", "O"]]);

  const changeGridByVal = (index) => {
    setGrid([
      grid[0].map((btn, i) => {
        if (index === i) return btn === "O" ? "X" : "O";
        else return btn;
      })
    ]);
  };

  return (
    <>
      {grid[0].map((e, i) => {
        return (
          <Step
            key={i}
            index={i}
            changeGridByVal={changeGridByVal}
            active={e !== "O"}
          ></Step>
        );
      })}
    </>
  );
};

export default TryPage;
```

Sandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/admiring-worker-hoxyg?file=/src/App.js